# MVC Datetime picker validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application.My  page contain two date time picker.start date and end date.My requirement is,
when anyone select the start date ,the end date should be calculated as start date +10 days.

also one condition, end date should not be less than start date.
How can i possible?

$(document).ready(function ()
 {

```
    $("#txtstartdate").datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            showAnim: "slideDown",
            showOptions: {
                origin: ["top", "left"]
            }
        });

    $("#txtEnddate").datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            showAnim: "slideDown",
            showOptions: {
                origin: ["top", "left"]
            }
        });

});
```

I am using jquery datetime picker.

I just used javascript code but when I select the datetime picker it always showing prevoius selected date.how can I get selected date on selecting the datetime picker?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () 
{
    $('#txtStartDate, #txtEndDate').datepicker(
    {
        showOn: "both",
        beforeShow: customRange,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        showOptions: {
            origin: ["top", "left"]
        },
        firstDay: 1, 
        changeFirstDay: false
    });

});

function customRange(input) 
{ 
    var min = new Date(2008, 11 - 1, 1); //the absolute minimum date
        var dateMin = min;
        var dateMax = null;
        var dayRange = 10;  //range of days


        if (input.id == "txtStartDate") 
        {
            if ($("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate") != null)
            {
                dateMax = $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate");
                dateMin = $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("getDate");
                dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() - dayRange);
                if (dateMin < min)
                {
                        dateMin = min;
                }
             }
             else
             {
                dateMax = new Date(); //the absolute maximum date
             }                      
        }
        else if (input.id == "txtEndDate")
        {
                dateMax = new Date(); //the absolute maximum date
                if ($("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) 
                {
                        dateMin = $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");
                        var rangeMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + dayRange);

                        if(rangeMax < dateMax)
                        {
                            dateMax = rangeMax; 
                        }
                }
        }
    return {
                minDate: dateMin, 
                maxDate: dateMax,
            }; 

}​
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/XdFpg/

Comment: Thanks for the reply..this code almost worked.but the problem is i tried to print the date seletced,but it again showing the previous date?so hope no event like "aftershow" is not there.

Comment: Yes Got the solutions..I used "onSelect" method..and now I am getting the current selected Date...thank you...